# Find Frequency of each element in 2-D array using C

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have an nxm 2-D array and want to find frequency (number of occurrence) of each element in the array. How to realize that in array ?

```
Input:
  [1,2,3;1,2,3;1,2,3]


Expected Output:
  1 occurred 3 times
  2 occurred 3 times
  3 occurred 3 times.
```

Thank you :)

Comment: are the array values static or dynamic?

Comment: These are dynamic values.